# Draw a button as big as the movie clip

Tags: flash, actionscript

I'm really novice with ActionScript and Flash/Flex.

I'm trying to implement a multiple file uploader and expose and API for javascript. Even though I think I can handle urlrequests, I'm having a hard time making a SimpleButton.

I want the button to have the size of the movieclip/sprite that I create. I'm trying without luck to make a movieclip of 130px x 30px, and have a simple button that fills the entire area.

What I try to do in actionscript:

```
private var _button:SimpleButton = new SimpleButton();
private var _fileList:FileReferenceList = new FileReferenceList();
private var _buttonShape:Shape;

public function FileUploader() {
   makeSkin();
   makeButton();
   addChild(_button);
}

private function makeSkin():void {
    _buttonShape = new Shape();
    _buttonShape.graphics.beginFill(0x000000,1);
    _buttonShape.graphics.drawRect(0,0,130,30);
    _buttonShape.graphics.endFill();
}

private function makeButton():void {
    _button.upState = _buttonShape;
    _button.downState = _buttonShape;
    _button.overState = _buttonShape;
    _button.hitTestState = _buttonShape;
    _button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickAction);
}

private function clickAction(e:MouseEvent):void {
    _fileList.browse();
}
```

HTML:

```
<object  id="FileUploader" width="130px" height="30px">
   <param name="movie" value="FileUploader.swf" />
   <param name="quality" value="high" />
   <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" />
   <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
   <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />

   <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="FileUploader.swf" width="130px" height="30px" >
        <param name="quality" value="high" />
        <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" />
        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
   </object>
</object>
```

I'm using intelij to compile this. I have no idea how to build it with the SDK alone. Any tutorial or hint would be grateful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer after reading a bit more. Stage scale and stage align were the problem.

```
public class FileUploader extends Sprite {

private var _fileList:FileReferenceList = new FileReferenceList();
private var _buttonShape:Sprite = new Sprite();


public function FileUploader() {
    stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
    stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
    createButton();
    addChild(_buttonShape);
}

private function createButton():void {
    _buttonShape.x = 0;
    _buttonShape.y = 0;
    _buttonShape.graphics.beginFill(0x000000,1);
    _buttonShape.graphics.drawRect(0,0,1000,1000);
    _buttonShape.graphics.endFill();
    _buttonShape.buttonMode = true;
    _buttonShape.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickAction);
}

private function clickAction(e:MouseEvent):void {
    _fileList.browse();
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can download either FlashDevelop or FDT Free as an IDE+compiler. I prefer FlashDevelop as it's rather simple to get everything up and working. However, both FDT and FlashDevelop have templates to start from.

Comment: Thanks for the suggesion. I gave it a try. I think I'll stick with Intelij Idea since it offers import detection and and code hinting to a higher level compared to FlashDevelop. I still need some help with making the button as big as the stage or something similar to that. :)